# Where can we fly a drone in Paris?

Tags: easa-regulations, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, france

I'm wandering if I can fly my Phantom 4 Pro in Paris. What are the restrictions? If it's not allowed, can I get an official authorization as I'm an experienced drone operator?

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=drone+paris+reglementation)? My french is very rusty but it looks like there's plenty of information regarding drone flight in Paris, e.g. [here](http://www.sciencesetavenir.fr/high-tech/drones/drones-les-nouvelles-regles-en-vigueur-au-1er-janvier-2016_36504). And there's even a [festival](http://phys.org/news/2016-09-drones-swoop-paris-champs-elysees-festival.html).

Comment: Here's [a general government guide](http://www.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/IMG/pdf/Guide_Aeromodlisme_v1-0.pdf). I can't answer your question about Paris specifically, but the guide isn't encouraging: no flight is allowed over built-up or sensitive areas (including monuments and parks), or in restricted airspace (which covers most of central Paris). If no one here has any local knowledge, you might look for a local club that could inform you about it.

Comment: As Paris is a prohibited airspace at low altitude (P23 up to 6,000 ft), a drone cannot fly within it. The text of the [préfecture de police](http://www.prefecturedepolice.interieur.gouv.fr/Nous-connaitre/Actualites/Prevention/Bien-utiliser-un-drone-de-loisir) related to drones, and the link to the [DGAC instructions](http://www.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/Drones-civils-loisir-activite.html). Here is the official map of the [restricted areas](https://www.geoportail.gouv.fr/donnees/restrictions-pour-drones-de-loisir). You may contact the PP.

Comment: @mins thank you for your comment, I'm a bit confused, in the map restricted areas the Seine river seems to be purple and not red, does this mean I can fly my drone over the Seine at 30ft altitude ? thank you again

Comment: That's not clear to me, as it seems there are two overlapping areas. But P23 also includes water areas. You may directly contact the PP, or as others also mentioned the [Férération d'Aéro-Modélisme](http://www.ffam.asso.fr/). That's what I would do (I'm living close to Paris). If you intend to fly for some time, a club will provide an assurance with the license, it may be a good deal and will save you the time to understand the regulation, specially now with Vigipirate active. I think a month ago flying over the Champs-Elysées was possible on a week-end, but that's a temporary exception.

Comment: Another useful information: [This map](http://www.aip-drones.fr/carte/aip-drones/) shows two "annexes": I is the no-fly (all regulated airspaces) and II for specific areas (hot spots) where altitude is regulated. As you can see annexe I covers a good portion of Ile de France.

Comment: Seem's like there no way to fly drones in the hole Ile de France area .. quite sad ... have to take the train and travel far ..far away to do what I love :/

Answer (score 1):

There is a restricted zone over Paris known as LF-P 23 Paris.
NO ONE (planes, helicopter, drones, broomsticks...) can fly over Paris from the ground to 6500ft... unless you have a special authorization, which you will not get for flying an amateur drone just for fun.

This zone is defined by the [Arrêté du 21 février 2018](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/jorf/id/JORFTEXT000036644850), click the link if you are interested in the technicalities.

Personal experience: the only drones I ever saw flying here were the fire department ones during Notre Dame's Cathedral's fire and during the July 14th fireworks, for the official video broadcast along with police helicopters with TV crews on board.